# How make image magnifier using singe image

Tags: javascript, jquery

Initially I made a image magnifier which will zoom when the user move the mouse over the image but now I want to change that into a lens zooming method should use only one image

Answer (score -2):

Did you mean something like [Magnifier.js](http://mark-rolich.github.io/Magnifier.js/)?

Comment: Something like that but zoom should be like lens not square shape and zoom should happen within the pic div not in other window